# Create custom image attribute for category size chart

Tags: image, eav, category-attribute

I want to create an image attribute in category which maps to size chart in PDP.
Following is my install script and config.xml file.

My attribute is created in eav_attribute table but it is not mapped to category table. So I get an error while saving the field. Can anyone help me with right code to create category attribute as well as save in respective category table.

**config.xml**

```
<global>
<resources>
            <catalogsize_setup>
                <setup>
                    <module>XYZ_Catalog</module>
                    <class>Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup</class>
                </setup>
            </catalogsize_setup>
</resources>
<global>
```

**Install script**

```
$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();
$attribute  = array(
    'type' => 'varchar',
    'label'=> 'Size Chart',
    'input' => 'image',
    'global' => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
    'visible' => true,
    'required' => false,
    'user_defined' => true,
    'default' => "",
    'group' => "General Information"
);
$installer->addAttribute('catalog_category', 'size_chart', $attribute);
$installer->endSetup();
```

Error while saving attribute in category page back end:

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'size_chart' in
>   'field list', query was: INSERT INTO `catalog_category_flat_store_2`
>   (`entity_id`,`parent_id`,`created_at`,`updated_at`,`path`,`position`,`level`,`children_count`,`store_id`,`all_children`,`available_sort_by`,`children`,`custom_apply_to_products`,`custom_design`,`custom_design_from`,`custom_design_to`,`custom_layout_update`,`custom_use_parent_settings`,`default_sort_by`,`description`,`display_mode`,`filter_price_range`,`image`,`include_in_menu`,`is_active`,`is_anchor`,`landing_page`,`meta_description`,`meta_keywords`,`meta_title`,`name`,`page_layout`,`path_in_store`,`size_chart`,`url_key`,`url_path`)
>   VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?,
>   ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
>   `entity_id` = VALUES(`entity_id`), `parent_id` = VALUES(`parent_id`),
>   `created_at` = VALUES(`created_at`), `updated_at` =
>   VALUES(`updated_at`), `path` = VALUES(`path`), `position` =
>   VALUES(`position`), `level` = VALUES(`level`), `children_count` =
>   VALUES(`children_count`), `store_id` = VALUES(`store_id`),
>   `all_children` = VALUES(`all_children`), `available_sort_by` =
>   VALUES(`available_sort_by`), `children` = VALUES(`children`),
>   `custom_apply_to_products` = VALUES(`custom_apply_to_products`),
>   `custom_design` = VALUES(`custom_design`), `custom_design_from` =
>   VALUES(`custom_design_from`), `custom_design_to` =
>   VALUES(`custom_design_to`), `custom_layout_update` =
>   VALUES(`custom_layout_update`), `custom_use_parent_settings` =
>   VALUES(`custom_use_parent_settings`), `default_sort_by` =
>   VALUES(`default_sort_by`), `description` = VALUES(`description`),
>   `display_mode` = VALUES(`display_mode`), `filter_price_range` =
>   VALUES(`filter_price_range`), `image` = VALUES(`image`),
>   `include_in_menu` = VALUES(`include_in_menu`), `is_active` =
>   VALUES(`is_active`), `is_anchor` = VALUES(`is_anchor`), `landing_page`
>   = VALUES(`landing_page`), `meta_description` = VALUES(`meta_description`), `meta_keywords` = VALUES(`meta_keywords`),
>   `meta_title` = VALUES(`meta_title`), `name` = VALUES(`name`),
>   `page_layout` = VALUES(`page_layout`), `path_in_store` =
>   VALUES(`path_in_store`), `size_chart` = VALUES(`size_chart`),
>   `url_key` = VALUES(`url_key`), `url_path` = VALUES(`url_path`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was because my flat table for category was enabled and after creating custom image attribute I did not perform re-index only after which the attribute will get added in the flat table if enabled.